# How to use some icons to write code with swift？

Tags: swift

I want to use some Chinese words to write code just like the picture I posted.

How do I use the characters instead of a specific statement?

For example, I want to use 若 instead of `if` when I was using the if-statement.

It's best to give an example.

[image: Picture]

Comment: You would have to write your own custom programming language. For example, the [ChucK Music Programming Language](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu) is actually C/C++ underneath. (Download ChucK to actually see the code that makes ChucK work.) Programmers using ChucK don't need to know C/C++; they just need to know the custom language constructs exposed via the underlying frameworks = ChucK. Swift and other "higher level" programming languages are built out of something different underneath. *I'm sure that's more complex than what you want, but just a heads up that it's possible to do!*

Comment: You could switch to [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org) ...

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The Swift programming language is made up of specific keywords such as `if`, `switch`, `var`, `let`, etc. Those keywords must be written as-is. You can't use any other word or symbol for those keywords.

And it's not just the keywords of the language. It's also any API you use. None of that can be replaced. You must use the API as written.

The only place you can use symbols is in your own variable, class, and method names, just like in your picture.

Comment: Is there a need to mention what `typealias` is in case of declaring data types?

Comment: @AhmadF `typealias` doesn't affect keywords. You could create a type alias such as `typealias  = String` and then use ` ` anywhere you need a `String`. But you can't type alias keywords such as `if`.

Comment: That's right, but mentioning that you could do it for changing a data type might be useful :)